# NodeJS readdir() function always being run twice

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to pick up NodeJS and learning more for backend development purposes. I can't seem to wrap my mind around Async tasks though and I have an example here that I've spent hours over trying to search for the solution.

```
  app.get('/initialize_all_pictures', function(req, res){
  var path = './images/';
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, items){
    if (err){
      console.log("there was an error");
      return;
    }
    console.log(items.length);
    for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
      var photo = new Photo(path + items[i], 0, 0,Math.floor(Math.random()*1000))
      photoArray.push(photo);
    }

  });
  res.json({"Success" : "Done"});

});
```

Currently, I have this endpoint that is supposed to look through a directory called images and create "Photo" objects and push it into a global array called PhotoArray. It works, except the function for readdir is always being called twice.

console.log would always give output of
2
2

(I have two items in the directory).

Why is this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the route is called only once?

Comment: I just use my browser and point to the base_url + route. I checked console and it seems to only be called once

Comment: Your `res.json({"Success" : "Done"});` is called before the async job is done. You have to put it in the `fs.readdir()` callback to send a response only when your photos are ready and stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the problem.

I had a chrome extension that would help me format JSON values from HTTP requests. Unfortunately, the extension actually made an additional call to the endpoint therefore whenever I would point my browser to the endpoint, the function would end up getting called twice!

Comment: Thats why I asked 'are you absolutely sure'!!